# jQuery .serialize() for post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I am doing an ajax request through post that contains a forms variables.

the data for the ajax request looks like

```
data : {
  somevar1: 'someval1',
  somevar2: 'someval2',
  somevar3: 'someval3',
  somevar4: 'someval4',
  form:     FORMDATA
}
```

as you can see, as well as the basic form data I am also passing through some other data.

this means that I cannot use jquery `.serialize()`

I am wanting to end up with something that I can send through so on the other side I can just do

`$_POST['form']['fieldname']`

is there a built in function do do this?

or what would I need to do to create one?

the possibility of running a function on the form that does something like

```
function postArray(form){
  var data = {};
  var name, value = null;
  $(form).children('textarea, input, select'){
    name = this.name;
    data.name = $(this).val();
  }
  return data;
}
```

over the form could work.

and having

```
data : {
  somevar1: 'someval1',
  somevar2: 'someval2',
  somevar3: 'someval3',
  somevar4: 'someval4',
  form:     postArray(form)
}
```

would it work?

---

I could use `.serializeArray();`
But on the other side I get

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [name] => name1
      [value] => val1
    ),
  [1] => Array
    (
      [name] => name2
      [value] => val2
    )
  ...
  [8] => Array
    (
      [name] => name8
      [value] => val8
    )
)
```

Which is close, but that requires me to either
a: loop over the array and convert it to what I want
b: every time i use it loop over it to find the right key

Comment: because, on the otherside when doing print_r($_POST['form']) I get back what appears to be what should be a get string. although I could explode this on the server side, I would prefer not to.

Comment: are your extra variables computed via js or served with the page?

Comment: with the page (yes I am aware that I could always set them as hidden inputs, however the form is generated via ajax and is different depending on circumstances)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode your form data as JSON using [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json).

`serializeArray` gives you an array like so:

```
[
  {
    name: a
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: b
    value: 2
  }
]
```

so you would **not** be able to access the data on the server side with `$data['fieldname']`. To convert the array to an object (so that you could access the data like you want to), have a look at [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery).

Of course you can also just use your own function (which seems to do something similar if you fix the errors<sup>‡</sup>), but you still have to use `JSON.stringify`:

```
data : {
  somevar1: 'someval1',
  somevar2: 'someval2',
  somevar3: 'someval3',
  somevar4: 'someval4',
  form:     JSON.stringify(postArray(form))
}
```

In your PHP script, you can then use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the form data:

```
$form_data = json_decode($_POST['form']);
```

---

‡ Here is a fixed version (updated from you comment, don't use `for...in` to loop over arrays):

```
function postArray(form){ 
    var data = {}; 
    form = $(form).serializeArray(); 
    for(var i = form.length; i--; ) {
        data[form[i].name] = form[i].value;
    }
    return data; 
}
```

If you want to fix it for elements with `[]` in the name, you have to process those elements manually and put them in an array:

```
for(var i = form.length; i--; )
    var name = form[i].name;
    var value = form[i].value;
    var index = name.indexOf(`[]`);
    if( index > -1) {
        name = name.substring(0,index);
        if(!(name in data) {
            data[name] = [];
        }
        data[name].push(value);
    }
    else {
        data[name] = value;
    }
}
```

but this assumes that you don't have field names like `field` **and** `field[]`.

Comment: cheers, slight variation again: `function postArray(form){
  var data = {};
  form = $(form).serializeArray();
    for(var i in form)
        data[form[i].name] = form[i].value; 
  return data;
}`

I figure why not use jQuerys built in functions if we can? Feel free to update your answer with this and Ill delete the comment

Comment: hmm, works good except that, if I enter this in the console: `$('[name=keywords[]]').val();` the output is `$('["what", "another"]` which is fine, but when I print the result on the server I get `[type] => email [keywords[] => another`

as the output of the pre How can I fix it?

Comment: looking to get `[type] = email [keywords] => array( what, another)` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try This:
        <?php 
        /*
         * As a Class File your-class-file.php
         * Decode jQuery Serialize Post String For PHP
         */
         class PHP_Serialize {
         function Decode_Serialize($QUERY_STRING) {
                  /*
                   * Decode form.serelize() jQuery Post String
                   * Return like $_POST['Form_Input_Name or ID']
                   */
                  $a = explode('&', $QUERY_STRING);
                  $i = 0;
                  $store = array();
                  while ($i < count($a)) {
                      $b = explode('=', $a[$i]);
                      $array_name = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($b[0]));
                      $array_value = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($b[1]));
                      $store[$array_name] = $array_value;
                      $i++;
                  }
                   /*
                    * Convert Array as an Object
                    * return(object)$store; 
                    * Use ........Object->Form_Input_Name or ID
                    * or
                    * Use as An Array .........$var["Form_Input_Name or ID"]
                    */
                  return $store;
              }
         }
        ?>
        <?php 
        /*
         * How to USE:
         * In Your PHP File (your-file.php)
         * Include Class File like include('your-class-file.php');
         * $Decode = new PHP_Serialize();
         * Use Function Like This $_POST = $Decode->Decode_Serialize($_POST['Query_String']);
         */

        /*
         * Demo HERE
         * you-file.php
         */
        include('your-class-file.php');
        $Decode = new PHP_Serialize();
        $_POST = $Decode->Decode_Serialize($_POST['Query_String']);
        /* Decode jQuery Serlize String AS a PHP Function if you not making Class file */
        $_POST = Decode_Serialize($_POST['Query_String']);
        /* Use POST String in your mySQL Statement Like This*/
        mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE COMPANY_NAME = '".$_POST['COMPANY_NAME']."'");


        /*
         * Here is Your form PHP File
         */

        ?>
        <form action="" method="post" id="your-form-id" name="your-form-id">
        <label for="COMPANY_NAME">Company Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="COMPANY_NAME" id="COMPANY_NAME"/>
        <label for="COMPANY_EMAIL">Company Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="COMPANY_EMAIL" id="COMPANY_EMAIL"/>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>


        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function(){

                var Post_String = $('#your-form-id').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                type    :   'POST',
                url     :   'your-file.php',
                data    :   {Query_String:Post_String},
                success :   function(return_value){/* On Success you jQuery Code Here*/}
                });

            });

        });
        </script>
```