# jquery serialization and getting values with php

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

May be it would be an easy question but I did not manage it. Here is my checkboxes like this:

```
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg3" value="3" />
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg2" value="2" />
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg1" value="1" />
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg15" value="15" />
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg14" value="14" />
```

And I am posting values with $.post method like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#not_read', function () {
    var inputs = $("input[name='msg_id[]']").serialize();
    $.post("user.php", {"not_read":1,"message_ids":inputs}, function(z) {$("#result").html(z)});
});
```

I want to send checked values to the user.php and with foreach loop I want to update reading status which checked messages. Like below..

```
  if (isset($_POST['not_read'])):
    if (intval($_POST['not_read']) == 0 || empty($_POST['not_read'])):
    redirect("index.php");
  endif;     

    /* I don't know what I must write here.
    $values = $_POST['message_ids'];
    foreach($values as $row):
    mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET read='0'WHERE id='".$row["id"]."'");
    endforeach;

    # Sure, it is not working...

 */
  endif;
```

Kind regards...

Comment: what does `print_r($_POST);` give you? (1:IF you tick some options 2:IF you tick none?)

Comment: When I wrote print_r($_POSt), it gave me Array ( [not_read] => 1 [message_ids] => msg_id%5B%5D=4&msg_id%5B%5D=3&msg_id%5B%5D=2 ).

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891974/jquery-serialize-for-post

Comment: so in jquery use `serializeArray()` and in php `$values=json_decode($_POST['message_ids']);`

Comment: Waygood, could you write foreach loop. I did not understand.

Comment: `print_r($values);` will show you the structure for you to write your processing loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there will be more checkboxes it would be better to separate them with class names.

```
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg3" value="3" CLASS="msg_ids" />
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg2" value="2" CLASS="msg_ids" />
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg1" value="1" CLASS="msg_ids" />
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg15" value="15" CLASS="msg_ids" />
<input name="msg_id[]" type="checkbox" id="msg14" value="14" CLASS="msg_ids" />
```

if you set up data, you do not need to serialize it. Especially when you send some data without serializing.

```
$('body').on('click', '#not_read', function () {
    var inputs = [];
    $(".msg_ids").filter(':checked').each(function(){
        inputs.push($(this).val()); //creates array of selected boxes values
    });
    $.post("user.php", {"not_read":1,"message_ids":inputs}, function(z) {$("#result").html(z)});
});
```

In php, as your id's are integers, make sure they are for sql. Allso mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should use mysqli* functions.

```
$values = $_POST['message_ids'];
    foreach($values as $row):
    mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET read='0'WHERE id='".intval($row)."'");
    endforeach;
```

or you could allso do:

```
$values = $_POST['message_ids'];
if (is_array($values)) {
function make_safe(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = intval($item);
}
array_walk($values, 'make_safe');
if (count($values)>0) mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET read='0'WHERE id IN (".implode(', ',$values).")" );
else echo 'empty array';
}
else echo 'was not an array';
```

Comment: Thank you ery much. When I removed ["id"] expression from $row, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @AivarLuist , could you correct your answer if Habip's comment is true ?

Comment: @Stephane Rolland, yep, removed it. Sorry that sayed in code only because i copied it from question code :-D